# What to do to enter BIOS

Tags: keyboard, bios, fedora, hp-pavilion

I have a HP Pavillion dv4 Series laptop and it needs <kbd>F10</kbd> to enter BIOS, but that laptop doesn't have a working keyboard so I used an external keyboard. Unfortunately the external keyboard has few key problems like <kbd>Backspace</kbd>, <kbd>Enter</kbd> key, etc which doesn't work when pressed (problem in the external keyboard hardware) including the <kbd>F10</kbd> key (which makes me not enter BIOS) also I have struggled a lot to download the Fedora Workstation (struggled for the past 5-6 days) and I have finally wrote it to a USB stick.

But now I need to enter BIOS.

Please help me on how to enter BIOS when <kbd>F10</kbd> is not working.

Comment: More possible duplicates or solutions https://superuser.com/search?q=enter+bios+hp

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>Esc</kbd> key is one more way.
Enter <kbd>F10</kbd> and <kbd>Esc</kbd> multiple times just after you power your PC on.

Comment: but when I was spam pressing F10 and F12 and del and esc it entered a menu in which the keys are mentioned, in that it said to enter BIOS press F10. Anyway I will try.